# Permission for snap applications

Tags: permissions, snap, notepadqq

I have some trouble with the Ubuntu `notepadqq` package. After opening a file from my apache webroot I cannot see any content. Saving the file is also not possible. I thougt this would be a classic permission issue. Therefore, I changed the group of the webroot from `root` to `www-data` and added my user to this group. Permissions are 775, so in theory it should now be possible for me to edit files in my webroot. But nevertheless, when I open a file of this directory with notepadqq, it still only shows an empty file.

When using `gksudo notepadqq` I get the following error message:

```
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

I figured out that notepadqq is a so called snap application and I wonder if this is the reason for my problems.

Can someone give me a hint how I could fix this issue (without using 777 permissions)?

Comment: Everyone coming from later versions of Ubuntu read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1135983/883154

Comment: @aderchox and what next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Snap problem

I got similar error message on 16.04 LTS MATE with Xorg:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"

$ export | grep XDG_SESSION
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="mate"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="c2"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"

$ snap list | grep notepadqq
notepadqq  1.2.0-2    115   danieleds  -

$ which notepadqq 
/snap/bin/notepadqq

$ sudo snap run notepadqq
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Aborted (core dumped)

$ pkexec snap run notepadqq
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)

$ sudo notepadqq 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Aborted (core dumped)

$ gksudo notepadqq 
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0

$ sudo -u www-data notepadqq /var/www/html/index.html 
2018/02/25 22:40:11.162682 cmd_run.go:562: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/var/www/snap/notepadqq/115": mkdir /var/www/snap: permission denied
cannot create user data directory: /var/www/snap/notepadqq/115: Read-only file system
```

So it is not Wayland issue.

May be it is other limitation of Snap. Anyway I reported [bug 1751634 to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1751634).

## Get deb-packaged Notepadqq and run it

We discovered, that notepadqq snap does not launch as root, so we

1. Removing it and installing normal version from [“Notepadqq Team” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~notepadqq-team/+archive/ubuntu/notepadqq)

   ```
   snap remove notepadqq
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install notepadqq
   ```
2. Then run it as normal user:

   ```
   notepadqq
   ```
3. And as root:

   ```
   gksudo notepadqq
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! The deb-packaged notepadqq works fine!

Comment: From 'sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq' I get http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu cosmic Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]                             E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @GeoffreyWheeler It seems that the package is not available for *cosmic*. You have to write package request to the PPA owner to support this release using [special form](https://launchpad.net/%7Enotepadqq-team/+contactuser).

Comment: not available even in eoan (19.10)

Answer (score 7):

So, I was having the same problem. Searching the Web, I found a solution in a brazilian website. Obs: the apt repository version worked fine besides being deprecated, but it was ugly in my system...

Install notepadqq with snap as you normally would:

`sudo snap install notepadqq`

Then, run this commmand:

`sudo snap connect notepadqq:removable-media`

It solved for me, as the file I was trying to open was in another partition... Or so I think!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone from Ubuntu 18.04

```
snap install notepadqq --devmode
```

Comment: I now run 18.04 but this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

notepadqq does not have all the capabilities of Notepad++. I installed the Windows version on Ubuntu 18.04.* by running the installer with Wine. It works perfectly fine and you get many more features and none of the problems you experienced.

Comment: I've tried this but it does not work. Notepadd++ tells me that the file cannot be opened because its parent directory does not exist.