# Applications not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap, disk-usage

I have noticed several applications that I installed from either Ubuntu Software or snap directly, don't work. I use Ubuntu 20.04, which I assume can be part of the problem.

I downloaded Space from Jetbrains and Standard Notes from these locations and I can not get them to work. When I use their commands in a terminal they do not do anything and when I try to start them with sudo, I get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
```

I am really lost with this one, as I am unable to find similar cases on the internet. I assume the problem could also be in the display drivers, but I remember that Standard Notes just stopped working one day. I did not changed anything about the display drivers, so I do not know what the problem can be.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009698/permission-for-snap-applications

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1009704/723997

Comment: It seems there are other similar cases on SE - persist in searching?

Comment: @CraigHicks - The links you give are for unrelated issues. This question is specifically for snap apps not starting, with no error message. Seems no solution has been provided yet.

Answer (score 0):

This directory you mentioned is only for **Root** access.

**Try**:

```
sudo su
# Enter your password
Sudo apt-get #program-name
```

**And,**

If you want to put your user into the **sudo** *Group* you can use this *command* in **Root Mode**:

`usermod -aG sudo #username`

For more details, Please check this;

***Reference***

[How To Add User To Sudoers & Add User To Sudo Group On Ubuntu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-sudo-user-on-ubuntu)

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I am unable to launch programs installed via snap. apt packages work just fine. There are applications that do not work, no matter how I install them. These applications just do not start when I try to open them. When I type standard-notes in the console for example, nothing happens. When I type sudo standard-notes, I get the folder that cannot be created.

Comment: Have you tried to run them in the `root` mode?